# how to update the nested object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to update object array in javascript.

how to update original_sample with sample objects sent as argument to the function and perform calculation as shown

here, how to do different calcuation `with payfee` and `without payfee` in a single function and update the object

Gotstuck and how to do in javascript.

```
// update the original_sample with sample2 values
var res = getValue(original_sample, sample2);
// update the original_sample with sample3 values
var res = getValue(original_sample, sample3);
function getValue(original, sample){
return original.map(({ fee, rate, ...others }) => ({
    id: 'trans'
    amount: amount,
    fee: +fee,
    rate: +rate,
    targetamount: (amount-fee)*rate
  }))
}
```

```
//inputs
var original_sample= [{
     id: "trans",
     fee: 1,
     rate: 2.2,
     amount:100,
  }]
//passed as input to update original_sample
var sample2 = [{
   id: "trans",
   fee: 2,
   rate: 4.0,
   payfee: 1%,
   amount: 100,
  }]
//passed as input to update original_sample
var sample3 =[{
 id: "trans",
 fee: 1,
 rate: 1.0,
 amount: 100
   }]
```

```
Expected Result:
//getValue(original_sample, sample2);
res= [{
   id: "trans"
   fee: 2,
   rate: 4.0,
   payfee: 1,
   amount: 100,
targetamount: 388.08
    }]

//getValue(original_sample, sample3);
res=[{
 id: "trans",
 fee: 1,
 rate: 1.0,
 amount: 100,
targetamount: 99
   }]
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you expect `getValue` to do. Could you please write a clear specification?

Comment: @trincot thanks for reply, `getValue` will update the original_sample with sample2 values, if sample2 property doesnt exist in original_sample, then add else update the value

Comment: Your examples always only have one object in the arrays. What should happen if `original_sample` and `sample2` have, let's say, 3 and 5 objects in them?

Comment: @ in my scenario its only single object for both `sample2` and `original_sample`

Comment: Then I would suggest abandoning arrays completely, and just work with the inner objects.

Comment: @trincot only the property might differ, like `sample3` does not have `payfee`  so in that case my `res` property `targetamount` should do  `(amount-fee-payfee%)*rate`

Comment: I suppose the calculation is not your problem, right? Just getting the properties in the target object. Or do I still misunderstand? Your "expected result" section does not mention any `targetamount` property. So I am quite confused about what you are after.

Comment: It would help if you would have a clear distinction between what is input, and what is expected output for that input. I don't see the logic right now.

Comment: @trincot apologies for confusion, updated the code, thanks, since if sample object has `payfee` property, then ` targetamount` should do ` (amount-fee-payfee%)*rate` else if `without payfee` then `targetamount` should do `(amount-fee)*rate`, update existing props in `original_sample` with  eg `sample2` else add new property

Comment: @Ori Drori if `payfee` available then `targetamount` should be `(amount-fee-payfee%)*rate` if `no payfee` available then `targetamount` should be `(amount-fee)*rate`

Comment: What if original  has a payfee property, and the sample object does not? Is there anything in the original object that can influence the final result? If so, could you add examples of that in your question?

Comment: Anyway I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you only have one object in each array, I would either abandon the use of arrays completely, or extract the object every time you have to do something. For instance like this:

```js
function getValue(orig, update) {
    var obj = orig[0] = Object.assign({}, update[0]);
    if ("payfee" in obj) obj.payfee = parseInt(obj.payfee);
    obj.targetamount = (obj.amount-obj.fee) * (1 - (obj.payfee||0)/100) * obj.rate;
}

// Demo:
var original_sample = [{id: "trans", fee: 1, rate: 2.2, amount:100}];
var sample2 = [{id: "trans", fee: 2, rate: 4.0, payfee: "1%", amount: 100}];
var sample3 = [{id: "trans", fee: 1, rate: 1.0, amount: 100}];

getValue(original_sample, sample2);
console.log(original_sample);
getValue(original_sample, sample3);
console.log(original_sample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.concat()` to combine the arrays, and then reduce the combined array to an object, by always taking the last object with the same `id` and calculating the `targetAmount`. Convert back to an array with `Object.values()`.

```js
const getValue = (original, sample) =>
  Object.values(
    original.concat(sample)
    .reduce((r, o) => ({
      ...r,
      [o.id]: {
        ...o,
        targetamount: (o.amount - o.fee) * o.rate
      }
    })
    , {})
  )

const original_sample = [{"id":"trans","fee":1,"rate":2.2,"amount":100}]
const sample2 = [{"id":"trans","fee":2,"rate":4,"payfee":0.01,"amount":100}]
const sample3 = [{"id":"trans","fee":1,"rate":1,"amount":100}]

const originalAnd2 = getValue(original_sample, sample2)
const original2And3 = getValue(originalAnd2, sample3)

console.log(originalAnd2);

console.log(original2And3);
```